# JniExport fails with declaration of string

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

Why is it that when I want to use a string inside my Jniexport function that the dll becomes faulty?

If I comment out the usage of that string like in the code below, everything works and I get "My String" from calling that function in Java.

But as soon as I include that line with "std::string test;" I can build the dll, but in Java after calling System.loadLibrary("jniBridge") get the message

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:\path\to\dll\jniBridge.dll: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed

**jniBridge.cpp:**

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "jni.h"
#include "jniBridge.h"

#include "string"

/*
 * Class:     jniBridge
 * Method:    instantiateAI
 * Signature: ()Ljava/lang/String;
 */
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_jniBridge_instantiateAI
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz) {
    // std::string test; // fails with this line.
    return env->NewStringUTF("My String");
  }
```

Comment: What command do you use to compile this code into a library?

Comment: the commands are: "g++ -c -I"%JAVA_HOME%\include" -I"%JAVA_HOME%\include\win32" jniBridge.cpp -o jniBridge.o" and "g++ -shared -o jniBridge.dll jniBridge.o -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias"

Comment: I removed the Main class currently to shorten the command - but still same problem

Comment: If you compile separately, don't you need to add `-fPIC` to the first compile command? Also, what does [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) think of your DLL?

Comment: -fPIC is apparently ignored. DependencyWalker says that it can't find the file specific (a lot of them) all starting with API-MS-WIN-...-1.0.DLL; and in the console: Error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found.
Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.
Error: A circular dependency was detected.

Comment: You seem to be mixing 32-bit and 64-bit code somewhere, then. Those API-* DLLs you can ignore. Is your JVM 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: My JVM is 64-bit

Comment: And the rest of the code involved? Is your dll 64-bit? Are its dependencies 64-bit? If you are in doubt, produce a report with depends.exe and attach it to your question. Alternatively, use [Dependencies](https://lucasg.github.io/Dependencies/), maybe that gives you a clue.

Comment: Most modules are build for x86, but the API-MS-WIN... modules are in the CPU column in red "x64". Including the API-MS-WIN-CORE-STRING..DLL; Is this what you mean?

Comment: If your JVM is 64-bit, your library should also be 64 bit. Did you download a 64-bit compiler (mingw64) or a 32-bit compiler?

Comment: a 64bit (the mingw64)

Comment: Please post a report or screenshot from dependencies.exe or depends.exe, then. *something* is mixing 32-bit and 64-bit in your dll.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200052/discussion-between-botje-and-hermueller).

Comment: This is only a guess, but what stdc lib are you using?  I noticed you are calling `g++` I presume though mingw?    Is the appropriate MSVCRT.DLL available for loading by java at runtime? You can try building with `-static-libstdc++` to see if that helps.